# How to enable/install PHP exif in Directadmin?

Tags: php, debian, vps, directadmin

I do not have my own VPS on da-debian 9. I have Directadmin installed and I'm using php7.2. I would like to enable the php exif extension. I tried to do it according to the instructions: https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=252 but after entering the last two commands nothing happens.

```
cd / usr / local / directadmin / custombuild
mkdir -p custom / fpm
cp -fp configure / fpm / configure.php72 custom / fpm / configure.php72
```

How do I enable php exif?

Answer (score 0):

after modifying the config file you must rebuild PHP with the following command:

```
./build PHP n
```